# jQuery .not() function, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

$(".navigation a").not(".navigation ul ul a").hover(function(){

```
    // Not working.

});
```

For some reason, ALL `<a>` elements inside `.navigation` still get the hover function assigned to it.

I only want the elements that are not inside `ul ul`.

The Html is structured like this:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a>item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>item 2</a></li>
        <li>
            <a>item 3</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a>item 3.1</a><li>
            <li><a>item 3.2</a><li>
            <li><a>item 3.3</a><li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>item 4</a></li>
        <li><a>item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.navigation > ul > li a')
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$(".navigation>ul>li>a");
```

This will select anchors that are direct descendants of li's which are direct descendants of ul which are direct descendants of .navigation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work

```
$(".navigation a").not("ul ul a").hover(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".navigation a").not("ul ul a").hover(function(){ });
```